# random selection from 1-D vector data

Tags: matlab, random, numbers

would you please share your thoughts on the following question

suppose you have a 1-D vector data like

```
Data=[ a1 a2 a3 a4..... an];   0<ai<100
```

how we can find a subset of data such as

```
Data_subset=[ a3 a7 a8]  or  Data_subset=[ a1 a17 a81 a92 a93 a100 a101 ]
```

which  best hold this condition : `abs(sum(Data_subset)-700)<10`

any idea?

Comment: This seems to be very similar to the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is known to be hard to solve exactly

Comment: I would call it the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: When you say "which best hold this condition", do you mean you want any subset that holds `abs(sum(Data_subset)-700) < 10` as true, or do you want the subset that has the minimum value of `abs(sum(Data_subset)-700)`?

Comment: Indeed it is more of a soft-constraint variant of the subset-sum problem, like mentioned by @beaker.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. it seems i have a serious Math challenge.  @Noel Segura: Yes. length of subset is not important, a subset  that their sum is  very close to a our constant. say, sum(subset)= S+/-s

Comment: If what you want is any subset that holds that condition, there might be a solution for your specific case instead of a general solution, that seems harder. What order of magnitude do you expect n and `sum(Data)` to be? also, what kind of distribution does the values have? That means, what shape do you get with `hist(Data,0:100)`

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of unique subsets (ignoring order) by

Unique = sum (((N-1)^2+N-1)/2) + N
from N=1 to N=99

So If you only need to do this for vectors of length 100, you would have only 166750 unique data subsets. In this case you should have no problem brute forcing the problem by testing each subset, that is if you can create a way to generate them.

You could use something like the matlab function perms(), which will give you every permutation of your vector, except that you should have something like 1e156 different permutations.

The only partial solution I can think of is to use randperm() and then create a loop which tests subsets of that random permutation

```
    nPerms = 100
    subSetsSaved = cell()
    cellIndex=1; 
    for iRand=1:1:nPerms
         randOrder = randperm(length(data));
         dataPerm = permute(data,randOrder);
         for jSub=1:1:length(data)
               subSet = dataPerm(1:jSub);
               if (abs(sum(subSet)-700)<10)
                     subSetsSaved{cellIndex} = subSet;
                     cellIndex = cellIndex+1;
               end
          end
     end
```

You could even use this random permutation loop to attempt to randomly generate all 166750 unique subsets.  All you would have to do is randomly generate, sort and test for uniqueness.  These solutions of course are not ideal in terms of efficiency, so if this is a problem you need to solve quickly or if your set is much larger than N=100, you will need a different approach.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your calculation of the number of unique subsets. From what I can see it's binary: each element is either in the subset or not, so the number of unique subsets is `2^n` where `n` is the length of the original vector.